# how can I fill NaN values by the mean of the adjacent column in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, numpy, rows, nan, mean

I have a large data set, and I have some missing value, I want to fill the NAN values by the mean of the column before and after , and in certain cases i have NaN values consecutive in these case I want to replace all this nan values by the first value of non nan can found
for examples :

```
   0   1     2   3     4     5   6   7  8  9  10  11    12    13  14    15    16
NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  29.0  30.0 NaN 16.0  15.0 16.0  17.0 NaN  28.0  30.0 NaN  28.0  18.0
```

The goal is for the data to look like this:

```
 0   1     2   3     4     5   6   7  8  9  10  11    12    13  14    15    16
29.0  29.0  29.0 29.0  29.0  30.0 23.0 16.0  15.0 16.0  17.0 NaN  28.0  30.0 NaN  28.0  18.0
```

Comment: Why are not replaced 2 values in column `11` and `14` ?

Comment: it is by mistake , i should replace by the mean of i-1 and i+1

Answer (score 1):

#### Updated Proposal based on your feedback:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Build the DataFrame (create list of dict)
items = [{0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan, 4: 29.0, 5 : 30.0,
6: np.nan, 7 : 16.0, 8 : 15.0, 9 : 16.0, 10 : 17.0, 11: np.nan, 12 : 28.0,
13 : 30.0, 14: np.nan, 15 : 28.0, 16 : 18.0}]
your_example = pd.DataFrame(data = items, index=[1])
your_example # (this is what you have in your question above as I understand it)
```

[image]

***Desired Endstate Outcomes for `NaN` Values*:**

**Situation A:** 2 float/ints on either side of the `NaN` --> calculate the average of the 2 values and replace `NaN`

```
Old: 16.0, NaN, 18.0
Modified: 16.0, 17.0, 18.0
```

**Situation B:** More than 1 (n+1) consecutive `NaN` values, replace the n to n+1 `NaN`'s with the first non-zero float/int in the column.

```
Old: NaN, NaN, NaN, 29.0
Modified: 29.0, 29.0, 29.0, 29.0
```

**Situation C**: If there is an `NaN` in the last value of a given column, write the last non-zero float/int to replace the `NaN` value.

```
Old: 19.0, 11.0, 0, NaN
Modified: 19.0, 11.0, 0, 11.0
```

---

#### Initial Proposal based on interpolate function

> Based on the data in your example and my assumption that using the mean of values before and after a `NaN` is the same as a linear function - I would use the `pandas.Series.interpolate` [function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) to achieve this.

```
your_example.interpolate(method='linear', axis=1, limit_direction='backward')
```

> The `axis=1` is critical to running it horizontal across your columns, otherwise it's set to 0.  `backward` fill ensure your starting `NaN` values are accounted for.  This can be changed and modified based on the documentation (link above). Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reponse , but if the first and fifth values are not nan , i want him to go to the fifth one and fill it with the pervious. i know that your idea is great and logic to fill the nan value, but i want to do  what is requested from me.. i think i should do a loop but i don't know how i can do

Comment: @MarwaAbboud, could you clarify a bit more? I don't think I completely understand how you're intending a `NaN` value be handled but agree that a loop could work if you want it to be as flexible and dynamic as possible. Here is the [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cNRi9Al8ENXhplMle5Rmlo_mTMV-_wVD?usp=sharing) from my code above -- I'm wondering if you could illustrate the example from your comment in code there to clarify? I would be happy to help troubleshoot this for you.

Comment: Hi @MarwaAbboud - thanks for clarifying in the notebook.  Here's how I understand an acceptable solution to this problem, does it look inclusive to you?  _[editing my answer above]_